# Terminology for orthogonal matrices with $\det(A) \neq \pm1$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, terminology, rotations, orthogonal-matrices

I know that the title has contradictions. That's why I am asking.

Let $A$ be a matrix of dimensions $n \times n$. Then $A$ is orthogonal(or sometimes orthonormal) if 
$$
A^{T}=A^{-1}
$$ 
However, what if
$$
A^{T}=\lambda A^{-1}, \lambda\in\mathbb{R}
$$
More specifically,

$$
A^{T}=det(A)^2 A^{-1}, \lambda\in\mathbb{R}
$$
What kind of a matrix is that?

**Motivation :**
Programming reasons. I have `Rotator` class, which can optionally do scaling as well if the user allows it.

Comment: To anyone who downvotes : atleast tell me why!!!

Comment: Such a matrix is simply a scalar multiple of an orthogonal matrix. I don't think there is any common name for such a thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THE matrices you are talking about are THE matrices that preserve orthogonality in an Euclidean space; that is, if $<x,y>=0$, then $<Ax,Ay>=0$. Moreover, it's also equivalent to say that they preserve the angles or change them in their opposite.

In France, we say that a transformation associated with such a  matrix is a "similitude"; it is said direct when det(A)>0 and, otherwise, it is said indirect.

Comment: is there a term of them?

Comment: In France, we give the name "similitude", it is said direct if $\det(A)>0$ and, otherwise, it is said indirect.

Comment: Please add that to the answer so i can accept it. Also clarification : "similitude" also includes preservation of angles?

Answer (score 2):

Since $A$ is nonsingular, $\lambda I=A^TA$ is positive definite. So, $\lambda$ must be real positive and $A$ is just *a scalar multiple of a real orthogonal matrix*.